# What is this error from tensorflow means?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I run CNN model on my new images dataset on AWS Ubuntu deep learning instance, and when i run the model, tensor generate error or warning message as in picture attached.[image].
Nothing is happening on my jupyter notebook for an hour and i had to interrupt the kernel. My jupyter notebook still hanged even after 30minutes killing the process.

What does the warning means?

#add command line executed

[image]

Im not sure if it is because i use CPU instead of GPU on my instance or because the notebook is from windows imported to jupyter notebook on ubuntu...

Comment: It is unclear from the example whether the program is still running and has something to do with the warning provided. In general, warnings should be addressed but do not kill the process. The fact that tensorflow does not return any output with fit could be that something is wrong before training starts. Could you post the stack trace when you kill the process?

Comment: i add some command lines used in my model and some comments if it helps. The notebook just said "it appears the process has been killed"..something like this and ended the running process.

Comment: A CPU installation of keras for a CNN is very slow, would you be able to switch to a GPU instance? If you dont have the capacity for that google colab could be an option for testing whether the GPU could be of influence.

Comment: yes my next action is to try to switch to gpu. Hopefully the hanging issue will solved (besides fixing the warning too). In the beginning i thought that the issue is with all the warnings or error. Thanks casper